# Open bash shell as root -script

Tags: c, linux

I need to write a program in C which opens bash shell as root. I could not find a function which would be do that. I try something like that:

```
system("bash");
```

but i don't know what next

Comment: The shell command you probably want is `su`, but that will require a password.  You haven't specified whether your program is supposed to give you shell without needing a password.  Perhaps if your user is on the _sudoers_ list, you could run `sudo bash`.  Or (dangerously), you could have your program owned by root with the *setuid* permission.

Comment: I change ownership executable file to root by chown and permisson by chmod 777 and it isnt working. Program should open bash as root without 'sudo' or password.

Comment: @Rysiek64 How do you run bash with root rights *without* a C program?

Comment: @dbush it isnt working for me.

Comment: @immibis sudo bash i guess?

Comment: @Rysiek64 Then have you tried `system("sudo bash")`?

Comment: What happens when you try the code in the linked question?

Comment: @dbush Just open bash shell, but not as root.

Comment: @immibis its obvious, but program should open bash shell as root without asking for password.

Comment: Is the executable owed by root, and are the permissions set to 4755?

Comment: @dbush executable owed by root and permissions set to 777.

Comment: 777 doesn't work.  It has to be 4777 or 4755.  That sets the set-uid bit.

Comment: @dbush Thanks, it's working i am stupid.

Comment: Why did you say you need to write a C program, when in fact a shell script would have been enough?

Answer (score 0):

By default, your program will open a shell and run other programs as the same user which itself is running as. That is, if you run your program from a root account, it will execute other programs as root. Otherwise you can try this:

```
system("echo \"password\" | sudo -S bash");      # note the different quotes
```

But keep in mind that hard coding your password is highly inadvisable.

Comment: I trying use your idea, but its error, 'mypassword' command not found

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to do it in C, here's an idea how you could do it on Linux:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main( void )
{
    int pid = fork();
    if ( pid == 0 )
    {
        # first argument: command to start ("sudo")
        # second argument: program name for sudo ("$0" in shell)
        # third argument: first argument to sudo, name of the command to execute as root
        execlp( "sudo", "sudo", "bash", NULL );
    }

    int status;

    // wait for bash to finish
    wait( &status );

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on Ubuntu 15.04.